# How is work converted to heat energy in reversed Brayton air-refrigeration cycle?

Tags: thermodynamics, work

It is said that in a reversed Brayton cycle, heat rejected at the *high temperature heat exchanger* ($Q_r$) is more than heat absorbed at the *low temperature heat exchanger* ($Q_a$).

Since the cycle undergoes isentropic compression and expansion, no heat is absorbed from the surroundings.

By Clausius statement, $Q_r = Q_a + W$. So I guess the input work is getting converted to heat energy, but how is this happening ?

( Also I know that during isentropic compression the temperature of air coming from the LTHE is increased more than the temperature of atmosphere so that the heat can be removed at the HTHE, but the total heat content should remain the same unless the input work of compressor and expander got converted to heat energy. I don't understand how the work got converted to heat. )

Comment: What type of answer do you want?  This question can be answered from an engineering point of view, or at the "molecular level" point of view.  Please be more specific.

Comment: Any one of them will do, but option no. 1 looks more suitable for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, in a reversed brayton cycle, shaft work from a motor of some sort is used to spin a compressor which takes air and squeezes it down, raising its temperature. That heat is then rejected to ambient at constant pressure, producing a bulk flow of gas which then gets expanded through a turbine in which its pressure and temperature is dropped and some of that expansion work is fed back to turn the compressor. So the work required to run the process overall comes from the motor or engine that spins the compressor.